# What day based on datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to track each date about what day (Monday through Sunday) it would be based on this code below?

```
DECLARE @DATA TABLE(
    Movie1 DATETIME,
    Movie2 DATETIME,
    Movie3 DATETIME,
    Movie4 DATETIME,
    Movie5 DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @DATA
SELECT '01/20/2010','02/15/2010','02/02/2010','03/31/2010','04/16/2010'
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you mean?

Comment: @FullmetalBoy did our answers help?  If not, could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking how to return the text e.g. "Monday" based on the date, take a look at the [DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) function on MSDN.

```
select datename(weekday, Movie1) from @DATA
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select 
datename(dw, Movie1) Movie1Day,
datename(dw, Movie2) Movie2Day,
datename(dw, Movie3) Movie3Day,
datename(dw, Movie4) Movie4Day,
datename(dw, Movie5) Movie5Day
from @DATA
```